# orm query in django

Tags: python, django

Hi im new using django and i dont know how make a good query .
this is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client')
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('SubCategory')
    product = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.product
```

my view is:
this is my view

```
def index(request):
    category = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request,'ganagroapp/index.html', {'category' : category, 'products' : products} )
```

and my template

```
           <section >
                {% for product in products %}
                <div class="product">
                <p> {{ product }} </p>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </section>
```

and when i type  Product.object.all() just i receive as output de field product and i need as output product,description,client.

something like the output from mysql

```
select * from Products
```

Comment: Temporarily remove the ``__str__`` function and try again. You are getting fooled by the print function.

Comment: Updated answer with template.

Comment: To avoid another disaster: ``Product.objects.select_related('client', 'subcategory').all() `` .. will fetch the related rows using a join query. If you don't do this a new query will execute every time you access ``client`` or ``subcategory``. If you have 100 products you will execute 201 queries displaying all the info in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are doing something like this:

```
products = Product.objects.all()
for p in products:
    print(p)
```

This will print the names of the products since you have overridden the `__str__` method.

If you remove this method you will see that it's actually list of objects containing all the properties you defined in your `Products` class.

To print the values you are specifying:

```
print(p.product, p.description, p.client)
```

The example above is exactly what is happening in your template:

```
<section >
     {% for product in products %}
     <div class="product">
     <p> {{ product.product }}
         {{ product.description }} 
         {{ product.client }}</p>
     </div>
     {% endfor %}
 </section>
```

You are just rendering the `product` object that will be resolved the whatever `__str__` returns. Access the attributes directly.

The data you are accessing in your template are actual python objects behind the scenes.

Comment: this is my view 

def index(request):
    category = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request,'ganagroapp/index.html', {'category' : category, 'products' : products} )

Comment: Include that in your question.. and include parts of your template that shows this info. I suspect this is a problem with the template. The code you pasted above is perfectly valid.